# Change field separator for sort-fields

Tags: sorting, delimiters

`sort-fields` and `sort-numeric-fields` work great; but the field separator is whitespace. I would like to use a different delimiter (e.g.: [colon-char]).

I want this feature because I find myself resorting the `passwd` files records by UID via `vipw`.

I suppose I could start a shell and run something like `sort -n -t ':' -k3 /etc/passwd` and replace; but that seems clumsy and `sort-numeric-fields` is tantalizingly close to perfect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the code for `sort-fields`?  Have you tried substituting a regexp that matches your preferred separators for the hard-coded regexp in `sort-fields`, which matches whitespace?  Untested whether just changing that regexp does the trick - but that would be the place to start, I think.

This the `sort-fields` code:

```el
(defun sort-fields (field beg end)
  "..."
  (interactive "p\nr")
  (let ;; To make `end-of-line' and etc. to ignore fields.
      ((inhibit-field-text-motion t))
    (sort-fields-1 field beg end
           (function (lambda () (sort-skip-fields field) nil))
       (function (lambda () (skip-chars-forward "^ \t\n"))))))
                                             ;; ^^^^^^^^
                                             ;; CHANGE TO
                                             ;; MATCH YOUR SEPARATORS
```

BTW, if such a change is sufficient then you might even consider requesting that Emacs Dev add an optional regexp arg that matches the separators.  To do that, use `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: I'm so dramatically lisp-inept, I did not consider writing a new `defun`; but you're correct; that's the elegant way. I will see what I can come up with.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `sort-regexp-fields`. (Don't change `sort.el` or redefine any of its functions.)

Comment: Please elaborate - explain how "Just use `sort-regexp-fields`" answers the question. Maybe say something about how to use it or what it does.

Comment: I agree with Drew, particularly since `sort-regexp-fields` wants a regexp that identifies the records to sort, not the field separator, so while you can use it to "change the field separator", for that case it might not be very comfortable.